# MKMapView zoom broken after adding a single tab gesture recognizer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I'm working on an application using a map on which the user have to add an annotation. Very simple. Problem is, right after I added a tap recognizer on my map, the zoom supposed to be triggered after a double tap no longer works. It seems to be a pretty common issue, as I found (and tried, I swear) a lot of potential solutions without any success.

The latest solution I tried (and I felt very clever after finding it by myself) was trying to retrieve the "built-in double tap" recognizer of the MkMapView, so I can reuse it in my "single tap" gesture recognizer. This is what I did :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *gestures = [map gestureRecognizers];

    for (UIGestureRecognizer *r in gestures) {
        if ([r class] == [UITapGestureRecognizer class]) {
            if (2 == [(UITapGestureRecognizer *)r numberOfTapsRequired]) {
                builtInDoubleTap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)r;
                NSLog(@"BOOM! Found it!");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Guess view did load");
    [self enableTapRecognizer];
}
```

And in my "enableTapRecognizer" method :

```
- (void)enableTapRecognizer {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *mapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePosition:)];

    if(builtInDoubleTap) {
        NSLog(@"require to fail builtInDoubleTap");
        [mapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: builtInDoubleTap];
    }

    [map addGestureRecognizer: mapGestureRecognizer];    
}
```

Problem is, it *never* shows my "Boom! Found it!" debug message. How come it can zoom after a double tap without any gesture recognizer? That doesn't really make sense, does it?

(I also tried using a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate so my gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer method returns YES...)

I'm kinda desperate right now, so if somebody has an idea... maybe something wrong in my map configuration?

I'm targeting iOS5 and running latest xCode.

Thanks !